# How do I generate random numbers using HC-128 in Rust?

Tags: random, rust

I would like to generate random numbers using the crate [rand_hc](https://crates.io/crates/rand_hc). The [documentation](https://docs.rs/rand_hc/0.2.0/rand_hc/struct.Hc128Rng.html) states:

> This implementation uses an output buffer of sixteen u32 words, and uses `BlockRng` to implement the `RngCore` methods.

I am very new to rust and **do not understand anything** in the documentation. How can I just generate a random number in a range 0 to N?

Comment: Just try to copy/paste their code, and then run it.

Comment: Just a quick heads up: You can click on the names of things to see where they're from. In this case those two things are Traits which list functions which can be called on an object. Random numbers in rust are handled through the [`rand` crate](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/index.html), so you'd need to `use` the appropriate traits from there to get access to the functions from the traits.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff What code would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minimal code using that random number generator could look like this:

```
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
   let mut rng = rand_hc::Hc128Rng::from_entropy();
   println!("{}", rng.gen_range(0, 42));
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=70decadd7bf66a11c5ca15f10f451d20))

You first need to create an instance of the random number generator, which is done by one of the functions in the [`SeedableRng` trait](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html). I chose `from_entropy()` above. Once you have an instance of `Hc128Rng`, you can all functions in the [`Rng` trait](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/trait.Rng.html) to generate random numbers with it.

Note that `Hc128Rng` does not directly implement the `Rng` trait. It implements `RngCore` instead, and there is a [blanket implementation implementing `Rng` for all implementors of `RngCore`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/trait.Rng.html#implementors). The split of functionality into two traits allows the `RngCore` trait to be object safe, but it indeed makes the API somewhat less obvious if you aren't used to it yet.